# Returning a sequence of items of known size

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, return-value

I'm writing functions returning a **known number of elements**, which I often find myself adding to another collection:

```cpp
// declaration:
std::vector<int> computeNumbers();

// usage:
std::vector<int> nums = computeNumbers(); // allocates a vector inside and returns it
allnums.insert(allnums.end(), nums.cbegin(), nums.cend()); // after this, `nums` is not useful anymore
```

Alternatively, the above could be written as:

```cpp
// declaration:
void computeNumbers(std::vector<int>::iterator outputIterator);

// usage:
computeNumbers(allnums.end());
```

*(assuming there's enough space in `allNums` in both cases)*

The 2nd option seems to save an allocation in my case, and seems to leave more choice to the caller in general, but also feels slightly less clear and straightforward than just returning a vector.

So, **in the general case**:

- What are some pros and cons I didn't mention?
- Is there any established convention on the matter?
- Are there other ways to avoid the extra alloc?

Comment: An alternative would be to write a function which inserts all the items from one collection to another. `void insert_all(C& allnums, const C& nums) { allnums.insert(nums.begin(), nums.end());`

Comment: I don't have an issue with the insert part, I want the best way to return a sequence in the general case (no assumptions on how the results will be used), avoiding the extra allocation if possible. I tried to edit and clarify my question.

Comment: One "hidden" con of appending elements directly into `allnums` is that if you don't know the number of elements in advance (hence, you cannot `reserve`), you may end up with up to twice as much allocated memory than what the elements will occupy at the very end (vector capacity is typically doubled). Just imagine that the last capacity growth happens exactly before appending the last number.

Comment: @DanielLangr Here I stated we know in advance the number of items returned, but good point still, wouldn’t have thought of that.